# Spinnaker logging out user after SAMLResponse assertion is no longer valid

Tags: saml-2.0, spinnaker

I've set up Spinnaker to use SAML authentication as per this guide: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/saml/

I have no problem authenticating and logging in to Spinnaker - the setup seems correct and I'm able to decode my SAMLResponse from the IdP.

In the SAMLResponse I see the following:

```xml
<Response Destination="https://my-service-provider.com/saml/SSO" ID="~" IssueInstant="2019-09-11T22:26:25Z">
        <ns2:Assertion Version="2.0">
        <ns2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">my.identity.provider</ns2:Issuer>
        <ns2:Subject>
            <ns2:SubjectConfirmation>
                <ns2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-09-11T22:36:25Z"/>
            </ns2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </ns2:Subject>
        <ns2:Conditions NotBefore="2019-09-11T22:21:25Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-09-11T22:36:25Z">
        </ns2:Conditions>
        <ns2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-09-11T21:59:29Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2019-09-11T22:36:25Z">
        </ns2:AuthnStatement>
        </ns2:Assertion>
</Response>
```

I've removed a lot of fields, but notice the `IssueInstant` and the `NotOnOrAfter` conditions - the `NotOnOrAfter` is 10 minutes after the `IssueInstant`.

The problem I'm seeing is that once the `NotOnOrAfter` is reached I am logged out and need to reauthenticate.

Is this normal behavior? Should I speak with our IdP to increase the `NotOnOrAfter`? Shouldn't my session be stored in the SSO cookie (which is present)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue when we were setting up the SAML settings with our provider. Needed to extend the `SessionNotOnOrAfter` to longer than 10 minutes.